# How to install IE browser on MAC machine?

Tags: macos, internet-explorer

How to install Internet Explorer 11 on MAC machine?

Comment: For questions regarding MacOS go to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) community.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your OS version.

If you are using windows OS, you could install IE browser.

If you are using MacOS, it is impossible to launch Internet Explorer on Mac. But, there are other ways to simulate IE for Mac experience. You could mask Safari as different versions of Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge, you could also install a virtual machine and launch IE for Mac that way.

More details, please check [this article](https://setapp.com/how-to/use-internet-explorer-for-mac) and [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8005770).

Comment: Ok Thanks.I want to launch the IE browser through automation script for automation testing on MAC platform. Will it be work in that case?

Comment: I think it is impossible. you can't do it.